# groovy script from Azure Devops

Tags: groovy, azure-devops

We are moving away from jenkins to Azure Devops for Builds. We have scripts written in groovy. We need to execute these scripts as Task in Build definition of Azure Devops.
Few initial lines of script are like:

```
import groovy.json.*
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
println "Start Read Template!"
def  repoName =""
def  PAT ="ubrhjhsjifndpfz5ikfxo3oa" // Set PAT here, not actual PAT
def tfsAccount = "https://xyz.visualstudio.com/"  // set TFS URL here
```

etc....

I read in one of other stackoverflow question which says that bash task should be used. I tried with first line in task as:

```
#!/cygdrive/d/groovy2.4.15/bin groovy
```

but no success.

PS: my agent runs of Windows

Answer (score 1):

If your agent runs on Windows you need to install on the agent machine:

- Java 8 JDK
- Apache Groovy 2.4.9 (Downloaded as zip and extracted to some local folder)

After you have the tools you need to set environment variables, open CMD and run these commands:

```
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101"
setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin"
setx GROOVY_HOME "C:\Users\user123x\Desktop\apache-groovy-binary-2.4.9" (the first path is when you extracted the Apache Groovy 2.4.9)
setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users\user123x\Desktop\apache-groovy-binary-2.4.9\bin" (the first path is when you extracted the Apache Groovy 2.4.9 )
```

Now the agent machine ready to run groovy scripts, in the build definition add Command Line Task (not Bash) and choose your groovy script.

[image]

Comment: I would like to add that you would need to do this for a Jenkins Agent anyways.  And if you really want to test this to make sure it works, log into the Windows machine and run your groovy script to make sure it will execute with no issues.